# Make leaflet map mobile responsive

Tags: javascript, r, mobile, leaflet

I have built a leaflet with leaflet package in R. Here a simplified version of the code used

library(leaflet)

```
# dumb data
Points <- data.frame(lon = c(41.889, 41.882, 41.891), lat = c(12.455, 12.446, 12.459))

# web map
wland <- 
  leaflet(data = Points) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(col = "red", 
                   fillOpacity = 1, 
                   radius = 5,
                   stroke = TRUE,
                   clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
                     maxClusterRadius=35, disableClusteringAtZoom=14
                   )) 

saveWidget(wland, "To:/Your/Path/map.html", selfcontained = FALSE)
```

I uploaded the html along with all javascript [here](http://slow-data.com/webmap/wland.html) . It looks fine on desktop, but on mobile it does not respond well: markers remain too small, etc.
Do you know how to make leaflet mobile responsive? Shall I modify sometihng in the javascript created by R-leaflet?

Thanks,
Jacopo

Comment: I found your question because I had the same problem, then I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453598/is-there-a-way-to-make-leaflet-map-popup-responsive-on-r

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make leaflet map popup responsive on R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453598/is-there-a-way-to-make-leaflet-map-popup-responsive-on-r)

Answer (score 8):

This is what you need. It's pretty simple: http://leafletjs.com/examples/mobile/

The import part is `meta` element for scale. In 2022 they recommend:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```