# Is there a way to make leaflet map popup responsive on R?

Tags: html, r, leaflet

I use this R code (data was changed) to create an html file that I keep on a server:

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>%
        addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
        setView(lng=2.333333, lat=48.866667, zoom=12) %>%
        addMarkers(lng=2.333333, lat=48.866667, popup='Test')
```

The problem is that when I render the file on a browser using a mobile phone, the pin and popup are extremely small and the size doesn't change when I zoom on the map. 
Is there a way to make the pin and popup bigger ?

Answer (score 2):

## The idea

To achieve this, you will need to use some **javascript code** that you inject using the function `htmlwidgets::onRender()` as mentioned on [this](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/morefeatures.html#custom-javascript-with-htmlwidgetonrender) R leaflet documentation page.

The **javascript** you need is some jquery code (a javascript library included with the leaflet R package) that will inject a string in the head of the generated leaflet html file to make the page responsive. Here is the javascript/jquery code :

`javascript
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">')`

## R implementation with reproductible code

```
# load leaflet library
library(leaflet)

# create the string for responsiveness that will be injected in the <head> section of the leaflet output html file. Note that the quotes were escaped using the backslash character : `\`.  
responsiveness = "\'<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">\'"

# build a leaflet map with a stamen background
example.map <- leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles(group = "Stamen",
                   providers$Stamen.Toner,
                   options = providerTileOptions(opacity = 0.25)
                   ) %>%
# add the javascript for responsivness
htmlwidgets::onRender(paste0("
    function(el, x) {
      $('head').append(",responsiveness,");
    }"))

# show the map
example.map

# output an save the html file of the leaflet map in the root of your working directory
saveWidget(widget=example.map,
           file= "example.html",
           selfcontained = TRUE
           )
```

## Verification of the responsiveness of the output `example.html`

Now your map should be responsive. You can check this in two ways :

1. open the `example.html` file created with a text editor and check that the html tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` is present in the `head` section of your file.
2. open the `example.html` file in your browser. If chrome, right-click, inspect and click on the mobile phone icon to show your page as if it was rendered on a mobile phone. If yes, the zoom buttons should be easily accessible (big size).